# Does global boundedness ruin Stone-Weierstrass denseness?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be any topological space and denote by $\tau_X$ the topology on $C_b(X;\mathbb{R})$ that is induced by the family of seminorms $(\|\cdot\|_\psi\mid\psi\in B_0(X))$ with $\|f\|_\psi:=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)\psi(x)|$ and

$$\tag{1}B_0(X):=\{\psi:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \text{ bounded}\mid \forall\,\varepsilon>0\, : \,\exists\, K\subset X \text{ compact} \ : \ \sup\nolimits_{x\in X\setminus K}|\psi(x)|<\varepsilon\}.$$

A result of [[Giles](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1971-161-00/S0002-9947-1971-0282206-4/S0002-9947-1971-0282206-4.pdf), Thm. 3.1] asserts that if $\mathfrak{A}$ is a point-separating and pointwise non-vanishing subalgebra of $C_b(X;\mathbb{R})$, then $\mathfrak{A}$ is dense in $C_b(X;\mathbb{R})$ wrt. $\tau_X$.

**Question:** Given $c : X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, can we infer that also
$$\tag{2}\mathfrak{A}_c:=\{p\in\mathfrak{A} \mid p\leq c\} \quad\text{is $\tau_X$-dense in} \quad C_{b\,|\,c}(X):=\{f\in C_b(X;\mathbb{R})\mid f\leq c\} \ ?$$

(The above inequalities are understood to hold pointwise on $X$.) More regularity on $c$ can be assumed if necessary.

Comment: Unless $X$ is locally compact, I think $B_0(X)$ (with $\psi$ required to be continuous) is not very interesting.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar The elements of $B_0(X)$ need not be continuous (and I'm indeed mostly interested in the case where $X$ is not locally compact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c\notin\mathfrak{A}$ in general it is not true: e.g.: consider the case where $X$ is the real line , $\mathfrak{A}$ is the algebra of the polynomials, and $c$ is the function $-e^x$. Then $\mathfrak{A}_c$ is empty.

If $\mathfrak{A}$ is also a lattice, it is true:
Note that for any $u,v\in C_b(X;\mathbb{R})$ one has $|u\wedge c-v\wedge c|\le |u-v|$ point-wise. Therefore   $\|u\wedge c-v\wedge c\|_\psi\le \|u-v\|_\psi
$ for any weight $\psi$, and $F:u\mapsto u\wedge  c$ is a continuous self-map on $\big(C_b(X;\mathbb{R}), \tau_X\big)$. So  $ C_{b|c}(X) =F(C_b(X;\mathbb{R}))=F(\overline{\mathfrak{A}})  \subset \overline{F (\mathfrak{A})}= \overline{ \mathfrak{A}_c}$.

Comment: Is your last equation obvious? (Unless $c\in\mathfrak{A}$, we will have $\mathfrak{A}_c\subsetneq F(\mathfrak{A})$ in general...)

Comment: Right, I think the thesis is not true if c is not in the subalgebra. E.g. X=the real line, A=polynomials, c=-exp(x). Then A_c is empty...

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly you mean by 'lattice' in the context of your edited answer?

Comment: Closed under min. So if now c is in A, then A_c=F(A).

Comment: Ah okay, so "if $\mathfrak{A}$ is *also* a lattice" means "if $c\in \mathfrak{A}$ *and* $\mathfrak{A}$ is closed under min". Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Like that it's quite a poor answer, I know :)