# Global control of locally approximating polynomial in Stone-Weierstrass?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gn.general-topology, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathcal{A}:=\mathbb{R}[x]$ be the subalgebra (of $C(X)$) of univariate polynomials.

Given $\varphi\in C_b(X)$ and $K\subset X$ compact, we know from Stone-Weierstrass that

$$\tag{1} \forall\,\varepsilon>0 \, : \ \exists\, p_\varepsilon\in\mathcal{A} \quad\text{such that}\quad \sup\nolimits_{x\in K}\!|\varphi(x) - p_\varepsilon(x)|\leq\varepsilon.$$

(Here, $C_b(X)$ is the space of all bounded continuous $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions on $X$.)

**Question:** Can the polynomials in $(1)$ be chosen such that $p_\varepsilon \leq \varphi$ pointwise on $X$?

*If the answer is affirmative, can we generalise this to the case where $X$ is a $\sigma$-compact and bounded closed subset of a Banach space and $\mathcal{A}$ is a point-separating and pointwise non-vanishing subalgebra of $C_b(X)$?*

*(Note for the general case that the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C_b(X)$ wrt. the [strict topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449834/does-global-boundedness-ruin-stone-weierstrass-denseness?rq=1).)*

Comment: $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is  not a subalgebra of $C_b(\mathbb{R})$. The "b" means "bounded".

Comment: No. For example $\varphi(x)=-e^x$ tends faster to $-\infty$ than any polynomial.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Thanks for the comment and apologies, I deleted one "b" too many (in response to Nik Weaver's comment); the original question is now restored accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this works. Let's say $K\subseteq [-1,1]$. Start out by finding a polynomial $q$ such that $\varphi-\epsilon/2 \le q \le \varphi-\epsilon/4$ on $[-3,3]$. We can then take $p(x)=q(x)-(\epsilon/4)(x/2)^{2N}$. This will approximate $\varphi$ on $K$ with the desired accuracy for any choice of $N$, and also $p\le q\le\varphi$ on $[-3,3]$ for any $N$. Finally, taking $N$ large enough will make sure that also $p\le\varphi$ outside $[-3,3]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer to the case $X=\mathbb{R}$. Would you have any ideas for the general case as well?

Comment: Nothing substantial, but if I had to guess, I'm a bit skeptical about this, even when $X=\mathbb R$ because maybe in general it could be possible for $\mathcal{A}$ to only contain functions that diverge to $+\infty$ at one end.